# Word to create a generic tool from a specific tool. Used in programming (and perhaps elsewhere)

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I've heard this before, where someone has made something for a specific project and then they `verb` it to make it more generally available.
The example I can think of is Ruby on Rails:

> It was originally created by David Heinemeier Hansson for Basecamp and
>   then he ________________ it to make it into a framework that was
>   useful for more than just Basecamp.

My mind wants to think it's an `abstraction` but for some reason it doesn't seem like the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Abstract makes sense to me, but yes could confuse some people. Extrapolate could also work.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of something like _genericising_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that might be the correct word, but it's not the word I'm trying to remember. thanks

Comment: Is the word you are thinking of "extrapolate"?

Comment: **Extended** would also be possible in this context, but I prefer the answer **generalized** below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To make it more generally available.

You pretty much said it yourself.

I would go with **Generalized**. 
This is also the term used in maths, when introducing variables in place of constants to make it more widely applicable.

> **[Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization)** (or generalisation) is the formulation of general concepts from specific instances by abstracting common properties.

Comment: This is probably the best way to say it, but the definition actually uses abstract as a verb, so I think my gut was correct with `abstract` but since it's  not used as a verb as often as an adjective I think it sounded weird to me. My dictionary defines `abstract` as "consider (something) theoretically or separately from something else" or "extract (or remove) something" and essentially that is what I'm looking for. When you've created a specific tool, you extract the underlying concept into a new tool.

Comment: @Canuk Abstract can indeed be used as a verb. However, the reason I would not go for *abstract* is; it's a technical term in software development and has specific implementations attached to it, that might not be translated well into other domains.

Answer (score 0):

Several times I've run into "***expand*** the functionality (of)", which may fit pretty well also here.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for ***enhancement*** (*verb*: **enhance**).

> It was originally created by David Heinemeier Hansson for Basecamp and
>   then he ***enhanced*** it to make it into a framework that was
>   useful for more than just Basecamp.

TFD:

> **[enhancement](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/enhance)** (*computer science*)
>   A substantial increase in the capabilities of hardware or software.

M-W:

> **[enhance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enhance)**
>   *verb*   (enhanced; enhancing)
>   *transitive verb*
>
> **2 :**  heighten, increase; especially :  to increase or **improve in value**, quality, desirability, or attractiveness
>
> - **enhancement** *noun*